# Не получается написать рекурсивную функцию

Tags: python-3.x

Помогите написать рекурсивную функцию, которая раскладывает число на простые сомножители. Например, 378 = 2*3*3*3*7

Comment: Помочь, или сделать все за вас? Если первое, то приведите свои попытки решения и опишите в чем возникли затруднения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помогаю:

Рекурсивная функция должна иметь условие останова - логично, что это аргумент 1, и в этом случае вернуть пустой список

Функция должна найти минимальный простой множитель (p), вызывать себя же с аргументом `value//p` и вернуть объединение результата рекурсивного вызова с `p`

Answer (score 0):

может так лучше?

```
x=input(':')
st='x='
while x!=1:
    for num in range(2,x+1):
        if x/num==float(x//num):
            st+=str(num)+'*'
            x/=num
            break
st1=st[:-1]
print(st1)
```